# How to identify if a request type is synchronous or asynchronous

Tags: java, web-services, rest, http, asynchronous

Actually,  my requirement is, client can call my rest based services in both synchronous (request-response) or in asynchronous (request-acknowledgment-response) mode. Now, based on the request type, I have to follow the mode.

Now, my question is, is there any way, from the request itself, by default, is there any indicator, which will tells the clients desire request-response model. 
Service protocol is http.

if not possible, then what will be the best practice, to handle this type of scenario.

Comment: i think this type of information should come in http header(if not automatically client should set some custom header ), so you can differentiate between sync/async and act accordingly.

Comment: If the client does not tell the server what kind of response it is expecting, how the heck is the server supposed to know? Servers are (as a general rule) not psychics! You will have to send *some* indication as to the clients intention. `respond-async` in one of the answer seems to at least be a standardized option (even though I don't know how widely used it is).

Comment: Your design have some problem if you're treating your async request not in the same way as your sync request. The client calls you asynchronously is client's design choice, that shouldn't have any implications on server.

Comment: @prakashb: that was my first reaction as well, but I think he's not talking about asynchronous handling of a single request on the client, but about the server processing the call from the client asynchronously i.e. immediately returning with a `202` accepted return code and then proceeding to process the request (usually with some way for the client to ask about the progress of that processing).

Comment: @JoachimSauer Ok - thank you, which makes sense. Then the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59894796/1480381) looks like the best approach,if the header is not present, then he should assume it's looking for synchronous response. I can't think of any pitfalls to this approach other than exception scenarios. If client does async handling, it can catch the error response and make a note of it somewhere. In this approach, he will need to keep polling to inquire about the progress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have the client specify its preference to receive an asynchronous response via a header:

```
Prefer: respond-async
```

You can find details here: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7240#section-4.1.
I am not aware of any way to explicitly request the opposite, a synchronous response.

Answer (score 0):

To differentiate between two request you can pass the attributes in the header along with the request.

If it is Sync Request

Set Header : RequestType : Sync

If it is Async Request

Set Header : RequestType : ASync

This is the easiest way you can use.

Comment: thanks for ur answer
.. but is there any way, where client explicitly don't have to set any header.. 
by default some indication will be there with the request

Comment: one solution is you can create your own HTTP client API and give it as a JAR to your client , so that whenever they will make a call they have to use your API that will automatically take care of this feature , you have to define in your API the same concept as mention above that will make life of your client easier. But again here the difference is instead of intimating ur client to set these parameters you are giving bundle API which is doing the same work on ur behalf.

Comment: thanks for ur opinion..
surely i can do so..
but then my services will be tightly coupled with this JAR.
 which i would not prefer...
I'm looking for some indication by default from the request

Comment: you can gain access to your internal system , but you can't gain access for external system, instead i will recommend go with API that will not be tightly coupled as per your case , because you are giving flexibility to call the URL but when someone calls the URL by using your API , your API is intelligent enough to append these headers along with the request. The only thing you have to do is you  have to tell your clients to use your API whenever they call your system.

Comment: bro, what if the external client in not java... this type of APIs will be the services regid. Even if I have to follow the explicit header concep, then also, proving specific APIs to call my service is not good way... better to provide documentation to the client

Comment: if your client is not in Java you have to give them their Language specific libraries like if your client is in .net give them .net specific API to call your system. Yes that's why i told you in the very beginning you can intimate your client to call your system , any way you prefer depends on you and your requirement. Providing document is a good way go ahead if it suits you...

Comment: Thanks for ur opinion, but my question was, is there any default identifier available with request?